# How to autoscale node pools in Oracle's Container Engine for Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm struggling to find a way how to automatically scale the number of nodes in a Kubernetes node pool in Oracle's offering. This is something I've successfully used on GKE or AKS to only have GPU-enabled nodes running when needed, which is a massive cost saving.

The documentation only reveals scaling in Instance Pools, which is an Oracle-specific tech not related to Kubernetes.

Is node pool scaling possible in Oracle's Container Engine for Kubernetes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With regards to autoscaling worker nodes in Kubernetes, most clouds use the open source [cluster-autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler) project.

OCI is in the process of integrating with this project to allow node pool autoscaling, and this feature is expected to be generally available in February or March 2021.